# Need Excel VBA script to move values from other columns to newly inserted rows

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for an Excel VBA script that will move the values from the other columns to newly inserted rows.  The values in column A contain reference numbers in Columns B through E.  These values have to stay with the value in Column A.  I need to insert a new row and move the value in the column to the new row.  I've started writing an algorithm of how I imagine the script would work.  I just need help translating this into VBA code.

start in Column C
if cell is blank, jump to the next row
If cell contains a value, copy the value
       +Insert new row and paste the copy value in the new row under column B

Before:

```
A2 contains eeee    
B2 contains 111    
C2 contains 2222    
D2 contains 333
```

After:

```
A2 contains eeee    
B2 contains 111     
B3 contains 2222     
B4 contains 333
```

Comment: Would help to show some example "before" and "after" data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data looks something like this:

[image]

Try this:

```
Sub loopColC()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    last_row = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

    For j = last_row To 1 Step -1
        If (Range("C" & j) <> "") Then
            Range("C" & j).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
            Range("C" & j).Offset(1, -1).Value = Range("C" & j).Value
            Range("C" & j).Clear
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

---

Results looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. My data looks slightly different. Hopefully this example will help clarify.   Before:  A:2 contains "eeee", B:2 contains "111", C:2 contains "2222", D:2 contains "333".  After:   values from C:2 should be moved under the B column but with new rows added to contain each value.  I hope that makes sense.

Comment: See edit, Made a few changes and updated the example data.  Does this better suit your needs?

Comment: It's almost there.  The funtionality works well on the first row.  Couple of edits left to do.  I have multiple rows of data like the example.  Could you have it go through each row?  Also, data in the columns could extend beyond column C.  Could you have it check the columns until "blank" is reached?  It looks like it stops the script when the first row in column C is blank.

Comment: I updated the post to use a different method for determining the size of col C.  Try it again and it should loop thru all rows in col C.

Comment: Great work!  what about the other columns?  Some rows may extend only to column B while others go out to column Y.

Comment: I just realized I could delete the blank column C and re run the script.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out: it leaves the original range untouched

```
Sub tester()

Dim rngSrc As Range, rw As Range, c As Range
Dim arr(), i As Long, x As Long, bNew As Boolean

    'set the source range
    Set rngSrc = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:Y20")

    'resize the destination array
    ReDim arr(1 To rngSrc.Cells.Count, 1 To 2)
    i = 0

    'loop through the range and fill the array
    For Each rw In rngSrc.Rows
        If rw.Cells(1).Value <> "" Then
            i = i + 1
            arr(i, 1) = rw.Cells(1).Value
            bNew = True
            For x = 2 To rw.Cells.Count
                If rw.Cells(x).Value <> "" Then
                    If Not bNew Then i = i + 1
                    arr(i, 2) = rw.Cells(x).Value
                    bNew = False
                End If
            Next x
        End If
    Next rw

    'dump the array to a worksheet
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").Resize(i, 2).Value = arr

End Sub
```